# Mathematical idea behind "Cut a hole in a piece of paper large enough you can walk through"?

Tags: general-topology

"Cut a hole in a piece of paper large enough you can walk through?". I have seen the solution.
What is mathematical idea behind the solution?I am looking for a mathematical explanation.Is it related to topology?

Comment: "I have seen the solution".... care to share it with us?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mw86PmCvYzg

Comment: The point is that a cut determines only the *perimeter length* of the hole, not the *area*. A shape can have arbitrarily large area for a constant perimeter.

Comment: @PatrickStevens You wanted to say that you can have a perimeter as long as you want with a constant area for the shape, didn't you?

Comment: Er, I got that the wrong way round :P sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can cut hole as large as you want.

The underlying concept is that, at the core of it, a line has no width, so you can cut a spiral (as said in an other answer) as long as you want. You just need to increase the number of circles, and you have no limit.

Answer (score 0):

You can cut a long spiral and expand it.

You can cut so that even an elephant could pass.

Comment: Though the circumference of the hole can be as large as you would chose, unless you can make the hole planar, nothing larger than the size of the paper will pass through.

Comment: @William Elliot Try to cut a long spiral. It's possible! Good luck!

Comment: I get it, even without cutting.  The hole is perpendicular to the paper.

Comment: @William Elliot  What do you mean. Try to cut the spiral. Try, It's an interesting enough!

Comment: Ok.  I did not get it.  I get a narrow spirial shaped hole.  Am I suppose to stretch the edges of the hole or otherwise move, bend or deform the paper?

Comment: @William Elliot You need to expand it. The spiral should be long and thin, otherwise it not turn out.

Comment: The only way the paper bends is by pulling the remaing spiral shaped part upward in which case the hole disappears.  To clarify what you are talking about, post a picture.

Comment: @William Elliot I don't know to draw in the net. See also the Martigan's post in this topic.

Answer (score 0):

The area of the strip you cut is limited to whatever the piece of paper you started with had (and can actually neither increase nor decrease, assuming an ideal pair of scissors, and that you dont' cut anything away). That means that the narrower you cut it, the longer it necessarily has to be (half as thick means twice as long).